# ruby oneliner vs groovy

Tags: arrays, ruby, groovy, language-comparisons

i was going through [railstutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec:heroku_commands) and saw the following one liner

```
('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0..7].join
```

it creates random 7 character domain name like following:

```
 hwpcbmze.heroku.com
 seyjhflo.heroku.com
 jhyicevg.heroku.com
```

I tried converting the one liner to groovy but i could only come up with:

```
def range = ('a'..'z')
def tempList = new ArrayList (range)
Collections.shuffle(tempList)
println tempList[0..7].join()+".heroku.com"
```

Can the above be improved and made to a one liner? I tried to make the above code shorter by

```
println Collections.shuffle(new ArrayList ( ('a'..'z') ))[0..7].join()+".heroku.com"
```

However, apparently `Collections.shuffle(new ArrayList ( ('a'..'z') ))` is a `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not having shuffle built-in adds the most to the length, but here's a one liner that'll do it:

```
('a'..'z').toList().sort{new Random().nextInt()}[1..7].join()+".heroku.com"
```

Yours doesn't work because Collections.shuffle does an inplace shuffle but doesn't return anything.  To use that as a one liner, you'd need to do this:

```
('a'..'z').toList().with{Collections.shuffle(it); it[1..7].join()+".heroku.com"}
```

Comment: nice... slightly shorter: ('a'..'z').toList().sort{Math.random()}[1..7].join()+".heroku.com"

Comment: Be aware that this will sometimes fail with Java 7 as they've moved to use Timsort by default and that expects comparisons between 2 values to remain constant.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a one-liner, but another Groovy way to do this is to add a shuffle method to String...

```
String.metaClass.shuffle = { range ->
def r = new Random()
delegate.toList().sort { r.nextInt() }.join()[range]}
```

And then you have something very Ruby-like...

```
('a'..'z').join().shuffle(0..7)+'.heroku.com'
```

Comment: I like this one the most; I think it is the Groovier solution =D Though I think using `Collections.shuffle` to get the work done in the extension method would be a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt. It is a one-liner but allows repetition of characters. It does not perform a shuffle, though it generates suitable output for a random domain name.

I'm posting it as an example of a recursive anonymous closure:

```
{ i -> i > 0 ? "${(97 + new Random().nextInt(26) as char)}" + call(i-1) : "" }.call(7) + ".heroku.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not as pretty as the Ruby counterpart but, as Ted [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972975/ruby-oneliner-vs-groovy/1973348#1973348), it's mostly because of the fact that `shuffle` method is a static method in `Collections`.

```
[*'a'..'z'].with{ Collections.shuffle it; it }.take(7).join() + '.heroku.com'
```

I am using the spread operator trick to convert the range into a list :)